# iPad 3 stuck on the iTunes logo

Tags: itunes, ipad, recovery

My iPad 3 will not turn on.

It started freezing up and would reboot and then it would have a black screen with white text. It's currently stuck on the iTunes logo. It will connect to iTunes but it will not update or restore. HELP!!

Answer (score 2):

Try holding both the power and home buttons at the same time for about 10 to 30 seconds.

EDIT 1: Try to connect it to iTunes on your computer. iTunes may offer to try to fix it for you.

EDIT 2: If all else fails, check out the "*If your device gets stuck during startup*" section of [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412).

EDIT 3: If nothing works at all, try using the Apple's [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263). If this fails, you should contact Apple Support directly as it might be a hardware issue: http://www.apple.com/support/

Comment: We have tried that. Nothing works! And now t just stays on the iTunes logo!... It is very frustrating

Comment: @Sarah If the screen is lit, unplug it from any power source and let it's better drain completely.

Comment: I will try that but before the battery was completely dead. We actually ordered a new battery thinking that may be the problem. This iPad is previously owned so I am not sure what exactly it's been through

Comment: @Sarah Out of curiosity, did you reinstall a fresh operating system ofter getting it? Since it was preowned, the previous owner might have had it jailbroken, and maybe that's why it crashed now.

Comment: We had it connected to iTunes and tried to restore but it wouldn't.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking... No we did not how would I go about doing that? Or is it to late?

Comment: @Sarah When you connected it to iTunes, did you happen to do the same thing as in "Edit 2" above?

Comment: About restoring the OS, if we can get your iPad to talk to iTunes, then it's not to late. Unless, it's just a hardware failure, in which case you'll need to contact Apple Support.

Comment: Yes we have done everything now it only does anything when we plug it in but it just shows the apple icon for about 10 seconds and then the iTunes logo pops up, and that will stay on there even when you unplug it.

Comment: @Sarah Check out edit 3. This is by far the most aggressive option, and you will definitely loose all of the data on the device if you do it.

Comment: I don't think we've tried this I'm not sure though... Thank you so much for your time and help! I will try this tomorrow when I have my husbands laptop. I will let you know what happens

Comment: @Sarah Good luck! :)

Comment: Hey Vladimir! Tried everything and nothing worked  but I think I may have figured out what it is, Some kind of debugger message? A kernel version or something like that

Comment: @Sarah I'm sorry to hear that. I'm actually out of ideas... Try contacting Apple Support. Maybe they'll have some other suggestions.

Comment: Good luck getting it fixed!